# What is the best way to show the long grid/table in mobile app?

Tags: mobile, tables, grid

I am working on the design of mobile app which will connect with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM and show the data in the app. Now in the CRM there are many grids/table which I need to show in the mobile app.
Any idea or design inspiration how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so, you should research whether your users will find all of the data in these tables actually valuable to view on a mobile device.

If the answer is yes, then look into responsive table patterns. Your app may not be responsive, but you can still learn fro the mobile design patterns. Here are a few resources I found:

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Personally, I would prefer transforming the table into a vertical layout like the first example in the second link. Horizontal scrolling is usually iffy, especially on mobile phones where users are even more prone to scroll vertically - in my experience. But there are pros and cons to each approach. In the vertical layout, it's more difficult to compare rows. Whatever you decide, make sure you test it with your users to make sure they understand how it works.